# Type rules of arrays and generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, covariance, erasure

In the last paragraph of Item 25 in the Effective Java (2nd), it's said:

> Arrays and generics have very different type rules. Arrays are **covariant** and  **reified**; generics are **invariant** and **erased.**

Could someone give better definitions of the bolded terms in relation to arrays and generics in Java? I wouldn't mind some examples either.

Comment: [this eric lippert blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx) explains variance, although it applies more to c#. Have you tried wikipedia?

Comment: I think I'll get more explicit answer to this question here at SO. I also think that there are other people reading this excellent book and might have a similar question as I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention if you were confused about a particular concept, so I'm going to try to just give basic definitions of *covariance* and *invariance*.

*Covariance* preserves type ordering, *invariance* does not.  What this means is that sub-typing is or isn't preserved (inverted in the case of *contravariance*).

So, if you had the following class

```
public class A {

  public void go() {

    System.out.println("A");
  }
}
```

and...

```
public class B extends A {

  @Override
  public void go() {

    System.out.println("B");
  }
}
```

With covariant typing (e.g. arrays), the function

```
public static void go(A[] as) {

  for (A a : as)
    a.go();
}
```

is perfectly valid used as

```
A[] as = new A[8];
B[] bs = new B[8];

go(as);
go(bs);
```

In other words, array types are exposed to the runtime or *reified*.

With invariant typing (e.g. generics), sub-typing isn't preserved.  So, for example, `X<B>` would have no type relation to `X<A>` other than `X`.  This is partially a consequence of generic types not being exposed to the runtime or *erased*.

However, you can still explicitly express *covariance* and *contravariance* in Java using `extends` and `super` respectively.  For example with the class

```
public class X<T extends A> {

  private T t_;

  public X(T t) {
   t_ = t;
  }

  public void go() {

    t_.go();
  }
}
```

The function

```
public static void go(X<?> x) {

  x.go();
}
```

would be valid used as

```
X<A> xa = new X<A>(a);
X<B> xb = new X<B>(b);

go(xa);
go(xb);
```